# Design pattern for single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I have a subjective kind of question and would look for answers mainly from a UI perspective.

Say I need to create 2 pages

> 1. login page
> 2. home page

On the login page, I would show Username/Password and on succesful authentication, I would display the home page. Now here's the catch, it should be a single page (e.g. single html file) So on successful authentication, the homepage would be shown (but the same html will be shown OR the address bar URL would remain the same)

How can I implement the same ?

Also using Object oriented JavaScript and assuming JSON data, how many JavaScript classes should I create and what would be they contain ?

Also as an extension to the same question, say if I allow user to login using their Facebook / Twitter / Gmail accounts as well, what changes would I have to make to the JavaScript classes (or objects) I created above?

So if someone logs in using FB, instead of showing my login screen, the user would directly be shown my homepage. Remember I need to have a single html file (for both login/homepage)

Comment: Sounds more like you're asking how to do the entire job. I would recommend you break this down into individual questions dealing with specific topics.

Comment: I just need the approach and not the exact code/solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several questions here. There is no genaral answer to any of this questions as an example ,
   *how many JavaScript classes should I create and what would be they contain ?* - It's totally up to you to decide. It's depending on your complexity of the page.

I think you need to go through some tutorials first.
http://www.asp.net/single-page-application
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something lightweight you could use the module export pattern as described here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth. Issue ajax calls and apply / remove html templates with js templates. Best practices for JavaScript apps always entail removing global scope. Module export pattern is no exception. This is true of all the big name frameworks as well (ember and backbone). If you need something a little more robust go with ember or backbone. If you really want to be cool use chaplin. http://chaplinjs.org. I only say this because it has strict memory management which is definitely needed in single page apps.